# Unused results from Entity Framework database call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, msbuild, dbcontext, compiler-optimization

Any decent compiler should [eliminate dead code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination), at least to a certain extent. However, I am curious how a compiler (specifically MSBuild) handles a situation like the following:

```
// let's assume LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var users = db.Users.ToList();
// more code that never touches 'users'
```

Since `LazyLoadingEnabled = false`, will the compiled code:

1. Eagerly load the results from the database call
2. Make the call to the database without storing the results

   or
3. Never make the call to begin with?

I was cleaning up some old code at work and I found several cases of this occurring, so I'm curious as to whether we've been wasting resources or not.

It feels like the right answer is number 3, but I haven't found any solid evidence to back up my claims. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Calling `db.Users.ToList()` is not something that's free of side effects. The call creates `User` entities within the context, so even if `users` isn't used, those entities could still be used. For example, if something like `db.Users.Find()` is subsequently called with the same dbContext, that function wouldn't produce a call to the database if the entity exists locally.

Comment: @jjj Interesting. Should I remove `ToList()` for clarity?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think referencing a DbSet property in a DbContext *might* trigger some DbContext initialization if the context hasn't been previously initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is #1.

Not only will this execute the database query to select all the records from the `Users` table, but it will fetch all those records and construct entities for each of those records in the `Users` table.  Very expensive if you have many records.  Of course, the GC will eventually collect the wasted resources.

If you want to prove the above for yourself, just add the following line after you create your `DbContext` to log the SQL being executed:

```
db.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
```

BTW, the `LazyLoadingEnabled` setting has no effect on the observed behavior.  The `LazyLoadingEnabled` setting determines if navigational properties are eagerly loaded or not.  In this case, `db.Users` is not a navigational property, so it has no effect.

Comment: Wow. So this will occur regardless of the fact that I'm not ever using that variable?

Comment: yes.  In fact, the variable assignment is irrelevant.  If you do `db.Users.ToList();` only, without any variable assignment, you will have the exact same problem.